# How to set correct view hierarchy in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, view, uiview, uilabel, hierarchy

Simple problem but can't find the answer.

In xcode, I have set up a simple UIView with dark background color and on this UIView I have put an UILabel. When I run the app, the label is not shown. Debugging the view hierarchy shows me that for some reason, the UIView is displayed in front of the UILabel.

How can I set the UILabel in front of the UIView? I remember encountering the same problem in XCode 6 and was able to bring the UILabel to front but can't now find any advice on how to do this on XCode 7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours of surfing the net I figured this out (5 min after posting this question...)

In Xcode, select main storyboard -> view controller scene. There under view you see all and indextree with the UIViews and UILabels you have set up. On the list, first items get apparently drawn first and the last items last. All I had to do is move my UIView above the UILabel in the list and problems sorted itself out.